# Multisite list all pages in site

Tags: wordpress, navigation, multisite

I have a WP multi site that contains 3 sites - sites 1, 2, 3

Site 1 and 2 are just one page but site 3 has multi pages inside.

I would like to show a navigation on the top of each site to the other sites.

I would also like to show the child pages in site 3 on every page.

I'm using this code here to create the nav for all the sites.

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <?php

          $the_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

          $bcount = get_blog_count();

            global $wpdb;
            $blogs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'",13, 'stack overflow'));

            echo($blogs->blogname);

            if(!empty($blogs)){
                ?>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="portalHome"><a href="dashboard.html">
                    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right chervonMobNav"></i></a></li>
                <?php
                foreach($blogs as $blog){
                    $details = get_blog_details($blog->blog_id);

                    if($details != false){
                        $addr = $details->siteurl;
                        $name = $details->blogname;
                        $id = $details->blog_id;

                        //echo $name ." is blog ". $id." / ";

                        if(!(($blog->blog_id == 2)&&($show_main != 1))){

                        $class = ( $blog->blog_id == get_current_blog_id() ) ? ' current-site' : '';

                        ?>
                            <li class="menu-item<?php echo $class; ?>" > 
                                <a href="<?php echo $addr; ?>"><?php echo $name;?> <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right chervonMobNav"></i></a>

                                <?php
                                if($blog->blog_id == 4){
                                    echo 'here';
                                    //show the nav for blog 4

                                    $pages_args = array(
                                        'title_li' => '',
                                        'depth' => 0

                                    );

                                    wp_list_pages($pages_args);

                                }
                                ?>

                            </li>

                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
                </ul>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

The problem here is it only shows the pages in site 3 when I click that link and go it that site.

I want the nav to show the pages in site 3 when I'm on site 1 and site 2

So the nav in each site should look somneting like.

```
        Site One | Site Two | Site Three

                                Site Three - page 1
                                Site Three - page 2
                                Site Three - page 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because wp_list_pages() will show the pages for the current blog you are viewing.  You'll need to switch between blogs when you load the page to populate the navigation.  Something like this:

```
$current_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();
foreach( $blogs as $blog ) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog[ 'blog_id' ] );
    /* your current code here */
}
switch_to_blog( $current_blog_id );
```

There is also a really nice, one page plugin called "[Networkwide Menu](http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/networkwide-menu/)" which does what you are looking to do.  What's nice about this plugin is that it caches the results, making the site load faster as `switch_to_blog()` is pretty process intense if you have a large network.